# Testing font button

Tags: mstest, gui

This is Microsoft interview question. Can some body help me with it plz ?

```
How would you test the font button in microsoft word?
```

Comment: Perhaps you could start by telling us how you would test the font button in Microsoft Word.

Comment: For what it is worth, a lot of people wanting answers to QA interview questions seem to hang out at http://www.qualitytesting.info/

Comment: If it's for an interview, the answer should probably be your own

Comment: Hey folks - I'd be interested to hear why nobody's voted to close this post. When I saw the question initially, I expected close votes, but while there are downvotes, nobody wants to close it? I'd have thought it was a perfect candidate for a close - no research, no response to requests for more detail. It's our community - fancy popping an answer over here?: http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/133/should-we-update-the-faq-to-indicate-that-interview-questions-are-not-acceptable

Answer (score 5):

I'd go to the I.M Testy blog http://www.testingmentor.com/imtesty/ ( BJ Rollison of MS ) and search for 'font'

I'd also get a copy of How We Test Software At Microsoft and read it

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do a Google search for "How would you test the font button in microsoft word", perhaps post the question to a few random forums, then follow whatever came back without even thinking twice about it.

Oh wait, no I wouldn't... never mind.

Comment: Agreed.   Note to self: next time I am interviewing candidates, let the recruiter know I'm going to ask about a 'test me button' on some page I make on a wordpress site.  Then search the intrawebs for people asking 'how do I test the testme button' and my site URL if I can match up any of them to a resume that's been submitted pitch that resume in the trash.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you approach this as follows:

**Work Out What The Font Button Is Supposed To Do**

- Open MS Word, search the online help for "font". Read the entries related to fonts.
- Have a bit of a play around in Word trying various settings.

**Write Some Tests To Check If The Font Button Does What It's Supposed To Do**

Use what you learned about the font button to write some test cases. If you don't know how to write a test case then try searching either on here or with Google.